# Regularity and rigidity of stable/unstable distribution for geodesic flow on noncompact negatively curved manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, anosov-systems

For a volume-preserving $C^\infty$ Anosov flow on a three-dimensional compact Riemannian manifold, it was shown by [Hurder & Katok](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ehurder/papers/29manuscript.pdf) that the Anosov foliations are always of class $C^{1, \alpha}$. Furthermore, if these foliations are $C^2$, they are in fact $C^\infty$, which automatically implies constant curvature in the case of geodesic flows on compact negatively curved surfaces.

I'm curious if there are any analogous results in the noncompact cases.